# Can clients block their IP address, without anyone knowing?

Tags: c#, asp.net, network-programming, ip-address

I am using a code to know the client ip, who is logged in to my website up to this it is working fine, but if the client blocks their ip then what I will get, will I get their ip, and actually is there any chance to block their ip in the internet connection?

Please help me, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not possible to block an IP address from the webserver. Ultimately, the TCP/IP connection has to know the address of both ends that are communicating.

This doesn't mean that the IP address that you see on the server is actually the IP address of the client, any more than it means the IP address of the server is the IP address that the client actually tried to reach.

If the client machine is behind a proxy or NAT device, you will see the IP address of the proxy or whatever IP address the NAT device is using for the specific TCP/IP session.

You cannot assume that HTTP requests from the same IP address are associated with the same browser, machine or user.

Comment: Hi william, Thanks for replay me, if a client machine is behind a proxy or NAT device then can't i recognize the client, or is there any other way to do so?

Comment: You'd need to use some form of assigning a session to each request. General ways of doing this involve a session cookie, HTTP redirects to modify the request URL, or HTML forms. Basically, you assume that a request that doesn't have an existing session identifier is a new session and you assign it a session id (using one of the earlier methods). Then that session id is what you use internally to track each user.

Comment: ya, i am maintaining a session and each new request is associated with a session id, till this ok, now i have a session id and IP of the proxy, but how can i track that user, any suggestions?

Comment: Once you have tagged the client with a session ID, you would use that ID to track requests that belong to the client making the IP address irrelevant. If you are using ASP.NET, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(VS.100).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is no possibility..

If anybody want to access your website , should be need to internet connection..

To connect in internet , each connection unique **IP address**

Answer (score 0):

You will get the IP but not necessarily the IP of the client machine. Some time firewall block the actual IP address of the machine and provide the same IP of the node inside the Firewall